# How do I build UITableViewGrouped in a Modal View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to build Grouped View in Modal View which is destination state from "+" button on the Navigation bar in main table view.

I have written this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //title
    self.title = @"Set";
    //addBtn
    UIBarButtonItem *addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBtn;
    [addBtn release];
}

-(IBAction)toggleEditing
{

}
```

Comment: Edit your message and add code tag to the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a subclass of `UITableViewController` named `MyTableViewController`

   [image]
2. use `presentModalViewController:animated:` in your current viewController

   ```
   -(IBAction)toggleEditing {
       MyTableViewController *tableViewController = [[[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
       [self presentModalViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
   }
   ```

And you will need a delegate method that tells the viewController from where you showed the modal viewcontroller that a row was selected.